# How to hide all input elements within a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to hide input elements within my form with the following code. But it is not working...

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>children demo</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <div>
         <h1 class="selected">div-1</h1>
         <h1 class="selected">div-2</h1>
      </div>
      <h1>xyz</h1>
      <form name= "demo form">
      First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      <script>
         $( "div" ).children( ".selected" ).css( "background-color", "yellow" );
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
         $( demo_form.elements ).hide();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you missed the `''` in the jquery selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `$( demo_form.elements ).hide();` is incorrect.

To select all the `input` elements inside the `form`, you can use `$('input')` selector

```
$('form input').hide();
```

If you want to hide the `form` itself,

```
$('form').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it should be done using css:

```
form.hide-inputs input{
     display: none;
}
```

and in jquery/JavaScript add the class `hide-inputs`:

```
$('form').addClass('hide-inputs');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide all the elements within a form/element with ID "formId" use the following: ( change the tag name accordingly to make it work where ever you want )

Better to have css:

```
form#formId input{
     display: none;
}
```

Using Jquery:

```
$("form#formId input").hide();
```

If you want to hide a specific type of input say for example "text" use following:

Using css:

```
form#formId input[type='input']{
         display: none;
    }
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("form#formId input[type='text']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the form by name, you need to use something like

```
$('form[name=demo form]')
```

I would recommend to use an `id` on the form you want to hide.

```
 <form id="demo-form" name="demo form">
    First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo_form input').hide();
});
```

Notes:

1. Check your syntax
2. Don't forget to close the form element

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[type="text"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>children demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
  
     <h1>xyz</h1>

     <form name= "demo form">
    First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </body>
    </html>
```

you are using `demo_form` but there is no class `demo_form` that should be use like

```
$('input[type="text"]').hide();
```

**you can see an example here**

Comment: The `demo name` is the `name` of the `form` not _class_